# Why is content removed after iterating through generator object when importing yaml file

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml

I want to understand why after loading a yaml file into a variable in Python using PyYAML, and then acting (getting the content) on this generator object created...the variable becomes empty.

#### Example

template.yml

```
doc1:
 atest:                           
   attr: attr0
 btest:                           
   attr: attr1, attr12
 ctest:                           
   attr: attr2, attr22
---
doc2:
 atest:                           
   attr: attr0
 btest:                           
   attr: attr1, attr12
 ctest:                           
   attr: attr2, attr22
```

#### Python

```
>>> file = open("template.yml", "r")
>>> content = yaml.safe_load_all(file)
>>> content
>>> <generator object load_all at 0x1079f9518>
>>> for doc in content:
...         print(doc)
... 
{'doc1': {'atest': {'attr': 'attr0'}, 'btest': {'attr': 'attr1, attr12'}, 'ctest': {'attr': 'attr2, attr22'}}}
{'doc2': {'atest': {'attr': 'attr0'}, 'btest': {'attr': 'attr1, attr12'}, 'ctest': {'attr': 'attr2, attr22'}}}
>>> content
<generator object load_all at 0x1079f9518>
>>> for doc in content:
...     print(doc)
... 
>>>
```

As you can see in the last call, iterating through the content variable generator object again after the first time produces nothing. The data is not there even though the variable still exists as a generator object. So why is it wiped?

Also, I am just starting to use yaml and my first thought was, "great, this will produce a dictionary of dictionaries" variable, but it makes sense it's a list of documents (dictionaries). What does not make sense to me, is why is the yaml file parsed into a **generator object** that is not subscriptable instead of a list, since that's what it is acting like. I guess I don't understand Python generators...aren't they just iterators?

Comment: Python generators are single-pass iterators. Once you've iterated over it once, it's empty. `yaml.load_all` is passed a *stream* of yaml documents. It provides a lazy iterator (in this case,a  generator) that gives you access to the individual objects in the yaml. If you want a list at the top level, do `objs = list(yaml.load_all(...))`

Comment: Ok, I guess that's a Python basic I should know. Thanks! It just doesn't seem useful/robust to load the yaml data as one then. Know of a technical reason why it's loaded as a generator rather than a dictionary or list?

Comment: Well, for starters, it is simply more efficient. What if it is an infinite stream? What if loading the entire thing into memory would fail, but you only need to work with each individual obj at a time? Again, if you want a list, just use `x = list(my_gen)`

Answer (score 1):

There can be several reasons for returning a generator object instead of a list in Python. Among these are efficiency and data availability.

In the case of reading a YAML stream of documents, it is less memory efficient to load all of those in memory in case you want process them one at a time with little or no data exchange between documents.

It can also be more efficient in time, e.g. for someone waiting for the result of reading the first document in a stream to show up on a screen, if you load the first document, show the results and then proceed to loading the second document, etc.

But the most important reasons is data availability: if you are processing a stream, that stream can still be written to and might not be complete: additional data might be added to the current YAML document in the stream, or additional documents might be added to the stream. Your file is just a (boring) edge case of a stream where the complete stream is available up front.

If you have a stream based API and use generators, you can easily make it into a re-iterable list if the above efficiency are of no concern to you by putting `[]` around the generator. But doing the reverse (presenting a list as an generator) doesn't make it memory efficient and will have you wait for any resulting list, until the stream is closed (i.e. in general you have no information if the final `...` of the last document in the stream is not going to be followed by another document).

Similar processing and presenting before all data is available is done by web browser and video showing programs:

- A browsers gets the main page for which you provided the URL and starts displaying it, although not all image are loaded. If you have lots of images on a long page and/or a slow internet connection, you can start reading before the page is fully loaded. And some image formats  support  displaying of low resolution images before all data is streamed in. (This was more important in the early 90's with slow modem connections than it is nowadays).
- If you are watching a video, you don't want it to load all the video, then all the audio and possible subtitles, and only then start to display the stream. It will probably not fit the memory of your computer if that is a Ultra-HD movie stream. And if you are watching a live video, all of that data isn't even available.

Such a stream based interface to get data might be somewhat more complex, but is more powerful. If you don't need that power (because you have a complete stream available), that complexity can of course get in the way of getting things to work as you expect them to.